# Heidi SQL 'Cannot close tab with running query'

Tags: mysql

I have a [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com) query tab which I cannot close, where the execute button is greyed out.

I have searched for this and the recommendations are to show process list and then kill the queries found in it. However when I run show process list all it shows is the process list query itself. Also the status bar in the bottom right is Idle, which according to other answers I've read should mean nothing is running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, dear, another case of a 3rd party software getting in the way.

1. Get a command window.
2. Open the "mysql" commandline tool.
3. `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`, identify the pid for the naughty query.
4. `kill 1234;` (or whatever the pid number is).

(If you were running the original query from "mysql", a simple CTRL-C would terminate it.  The above stuff would not be needed.)

Comment: Thanks Rick - although I'm not sure if it worked as I stopped the program completely before I read your post. So you don't like HeidiSQL? I am a noob with this, I asked IT  to have SQL installed on my PC and I got Heidi, I was a bit put off at first as the training videos I have watched all use MySQL Workbench, but it seemed to be ok once I started using it (until now)

Comment: Too many of the questions I answer on these forums ask how to work around what seems like a limitation in the 3rd party software they are using.  HeidiSQL is one of probably more than 20; I don't have time to form an opinion about any one.  (So, I lump them all together.)  I get especially irritated when the user has millions of rows, and can't figure how to make the queries (generated by the software) perform well enough.  All I can say is "You need to write it this way: 'SELECT ...', but can't explain how to achieve that in product X.